# Optimize tableView insertion in CoronaSDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

This code takes two seconds to process.

```
print("before loop scholarships:"..system.getTimer())
for i = 1, scholarshipTableSize  do

-- Insert the row into the tableView
tableView:insertRow
{
    isCategory = false,
    rowHeight = 75,
    rowColor =      
    { 
        default = { 255, 232, 4 },
        over = { 0, 158, 255 },
    },
    lineColor = { 0, 0, 0 },
}
end
```

scholarshipTableSize is somewhere around 1200. How can I optimize this insertion so that it performs faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I updated to the latest corona build, the time was much better. around 2 ms.

Now I am using build 2013.1137